# Problems in h2 version 1.4.x when using the "shutdown compact" statement

Tags: java, h2

Is there some known issue with the mv engine in newer h2 versions and the "shutdown compact" statement ?

I have some java code written originally using the h2 v1.3.175 jar library to create and access embedded databases on a hobby programming project that worked fine, but I recently decided to upgrade the jar to the current version v1.4.181 and i began  having "chunk not found" errors , and after that the database seems to get corrupted and i cant connect either from my java code or the web console.

The error is: `General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 10 not found [1.4.181/6]" [50000-181] HY000/50000`

After checking my java code i found that the problem seems to be the "shutdown compact" statement i was using in my code before disconnecting the database. Deleting that statement solved the problem.

Comment: I am also fighting with this Chunk-not-found-error in 1.4.200. I was also doing SHUTDOWN COMPACT daily on startup.